# Probability of correct estimation of a rectangular area

Tags: probability

Suppose that we ask participants to estimate the area of a rectangle with length L and width W from a distance. what is the probability of correctly estimating the rectangular area? The area is length$\times$width, and therefore the estimate is a combination of correct (C) or incorrect (I) estimation of each side. There are four possible outcomes - CC, CI, IC, I*I. Therefore there is only one correct estimation and three incorrect estimations. Is the probability of correct estimation (1/4) or 0.25? If not could anyone explain this here?

Comment: I would say the probability of correct estimation is 0, if that L = 6.3857 feet and W =2.4321 feet and define the correct as |guess-real|< 0.001 feet.

Comment: 1. Unambiguously define "correct" when you have a continuous length. 2. Why would "correct" and "incorrect" be equally likely? That would seem to be an astonishing coincidence. 3.Factors leading to bias in guessing the size in one direction would mostly tend to be factors affecting the guess for the other direction, so treating the two as independent would seem to be a risky idea.

Comment: I'm sorry but I also think you should consider the probability of getting the correct area from incorrect length and width. I think that the main question is that, in order to be able to compute a probability, we would need to know something more about that problem. For instance: are the measurements treated as continuous or as discrete variables (e.g., if there are closed options); what are the distributions of the width, the length and/or the area?